# gets() doesnot allow execution of cout first

Tags: c++, c++03, c++98

I am currently using 'Digital Mars C++' as I needed Turbo C++ like Syntax and 32-bit exe build so that's the reason.

Now my problem that I am facing is that when I write the code below,

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char n[30];
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    gets(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I save this file then I save this file as `test.cpp`.

Then I opened my command prompt and typed `dmc test.cpp`.

Now as I got a compiled file the exe file `test.exe`, now when I run it it's first asking for input then it displays a message `Enter Name:`.

Please help me with this problem it is really necessary.

NOTE :

- when I use printf instead of cout it works fine.
- and when I replace my statement
  `cout << " Enter Name: ";`
  with 
  `cout << " Enter Name: " << endl` then also i get my message and then asks input.

Please do not suggest me of using the GCC compiler.

And I would be glad if you direct me where to make changes in my stdio.h file to get rectified gets function to work properly or any such other header file which is related to fixing this error.

Comment: Have you tried `cout << "Enter Name: " << flush;`?

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's an old and **dangerous** function and has therefore been either obsoleted and now even *removed* from both the C and C++ specifications.

Comment: What does flush do.

Comment: why do you *need* Turbo C++-like Syntax? 32-bit build is irrelevant here as there are tons of 32-bit compilers for each platform

Comment: And *please* get a more up to date compiler. You're learning the ancient pre-standard C++.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714) @hlt there's no STL in Turbo C++ so no cout either

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I get that but still if I am trying to make a Turbo C like editor then I need to use get function I know it's dangerous to use it but as I am trying to make an editor just like Turbo C4 so I need the syntax that my teachers use in our school to run efficiently in my compiler some trying to fix the gets function problem please tell me where can I make the changes in the header file to get it right

Comment: Well he is using `cout` (and says it works with `endl`) so I'm not entirely sure about that @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Comment: @Nikhil Standard output is buffered, and usually only sent to the console at the end of a line (?), `flush` manually tells it to send everything in the buffer out.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I know but is that stupid education system in our in my country that enforces the 11th grade students to use Turbo C plus plus compiler colours.

Comment: Being forced to use Turbo C... my condolences

Comment: @hlt believe me bro I have tried it in Turbo C4 the same code that I'm presenting to you now and it works.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc please elaborate what is STL I am new to it.

And bro believe me Turbo C4 supports use of COUT

Comment: Use fgets or cin  or getline instead of gets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Add this code,

```
 cout << flush;
```

just before using `cout << "Some Statement";`
 **or**
In direct approach you can do this `cout << " Some Statement" << flush;` then use `gets()` with ease.